# How to integrate Flutter app's build process with Rust code? i.e. when building Flutter code, how to automatically build its Rust code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, rust

I have a Flutter application that also has some Rust code, and they communicate via [flutter_rust_bridge](https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_rust_bridge). There are already some tutorials talking about how to build such an app. However, they require me to manually trigger `cargo build` (or similar commands) and `flutter run` separately. You know, this is quite cumbersome, and if I forget to execute cargo, or that command fails, I run the risk of building a Flutter app with an old binary. Therefore, I wonder how I can automate that process. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Android

Add the following to your `build.gradle`

```
[
        new Tuple2('Debug', 'debug'),
        new Tuple2('Profile', 'release'),
        new Tuple2('Release', 'release')
].each {
    def taskPostfix = it.first
    def profileMode = it.second
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == "javaPreCompile$taskPostfix") {
            println "hello let ${task.name} dependsOn cargoBuild$taskPostfix"
            task.dependsOn "cargoBuild$taskPostfix"
        }
    }
    tasks.register("cargoBuild$taskPostfix", Exec) {
        println "hello executing doLast for task cargoBuild$taskPostfix"
        commandLine 'sh', '-c', "build-your-rust-code"
    }
}
```

where `build-your-rust-code` is the command you use to build your Rust code. (For example, I use fastlane to wrap it (of course you can use others) and I put that in a rust folder, so I just call `cd $projectDir/../rust/fastlane && bundle exec fastlane build_android profile:$profileMode`.)

### iOS

#### Method 1

The most manual way is as follows. Go to `Build Phases`, click `+` button and choose `New Run Script Phase`. Then enter the script you want to run to build your Rust code. (For example, for myself, I use Shell `/bin/sh` and call some fastlane commands which executes the actual commands.)

[image]

#### Method 2

A more automated approach is to use the CocoaPod files, which will automatically help you set up everything. For example, I add:

```
  s.script_phase = {
      :name => 'Compile Rust',
      :script => your-script-to-compile-it,
      :execution_position => :before_compile,
      :shell_path => '/bin/sh'
   }
```

(For example, my script is `%q{env -i HOME="$HOME" PROJECT_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR" CONFIGURATION="$CONFIGURATION" /bin/bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc && cd $PROJECT_DIR/../.symlinks/plugins/vision_utils/rust/fastlane && LC_ALL= LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bundle exec fastlane build_ios profile:$CONFIGURATION'}`. Notice that, at least in my case, I have to create a brand new shell. Otherwise the opencv in my Rust complains and fails to compile. But you may not have this problem if your Rust code does not contain c++ things.)

(Q&A style answer in order to help people who face the same situation as me, especially when not familiar with Android and iOS)